# Two halves fragments in a single layout one below another

Tags: android, native

That's my .xml code.
1st fragment is scanner_fragment for scanning barcode purpose.
2nd fragment is content_fragment for showing results of scanned barcode and submit buttons inside that.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



    <fragment android:name="me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.sample.SimpleScannerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/scanner_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"




        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**I want to put content fragment just below of scanner fragment**

**I want to put more views like listview inside content_fragment. how to overcome this ?**

Nailed it!
Here are the changes below.

**activity_scan.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <fragment android:name="com.example."
        android:id="@+id/scanner_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="356dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/scan_result"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

And for   tools:layout="@layout/scan_result"
**scan_result.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="600dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Reset" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirm" />


    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

-Use linear layout instead of relative layout

-For the linear layout put `android:weightSum="2"`

-Every frame layout should have `android:layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 0):

Use layout below attribute.

```
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <fragment android:name="me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.sample.SimpleScannerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/scanner_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/scanner_fragment"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I want fragments one below another, while this code gives fragments adjacent to another, which I'm not needed.

Comment: I've solved it by myself, thank you too. See the changes above.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear Layout and give this property to all framLayout

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

I hope that's helps you!

Thank You.

Comment: I want content fragment below of scanner fragment